# Why is my collapsible not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble getting this collapsible to work. It has something to do with the div, because on the 2nd collapsible, I removed the containing div and it works fine. What's the problem?

https://codepen.io/TheConnorCraig/pen/eLdaVQ

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("cbCollapse");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.cbCollapseRow {
  display: flex;
}

.cbCollapse {
  background-image: url('https://www.pitsco.com/skins/mobile/PlusIcon.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbCollapseRow">
  <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
  <h2>Sample 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<button class="cbCollapse"></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="cbCollapseRow">
  <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
  <h2>Sample 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your element is not expanding with the containing div is due to the `nextElementSibling()` you are targeting. This is causing your `<h2>` to receive the max-height styling.

If you want to keep the container on all of them, you can change it to `this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;` and the current code will work. [see this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOEXEB)

This will however break the div that is not wrapped. If you wanted to wrap them all though, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting `nextElementSibling` in your code, so you need to move your `button` html just above the `div` you want to collapse / expand.

For example (messes up the alignment you probably want for your `h2` tags but illustrates the issue):

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("cbCollapse");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.cbCollapseRow {
  display: flex;
}

.cbCollapse {
  background-image: url('https://www.pitsco.com/skins/mobile/PlusIcon.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbCollapseRow">
  <h2>Sample 1</h2>
</div>
<button class="cbCollapse"></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<button class="cbCollapse"></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>


<div class="cbCollapseRow">
  <h2>Sample 3</h2>
</div>
<button class="cbCollapse"></button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`nextElementSibling` should speak by itself. It's not a sibling in your case.

Also, try not to create/assign functions inside for loops.
Here's a remake using the `data-*` attribute to target desired *Content* elements 
ID

```js
const collapseTarget = (evt) => {
  const btn = evt.currentTarget;
  const id = btn.getAttribute("data-collapse");
  const cont = document.querySelector(id);
  btn.classList.toggle("active");
  cont.style.maxHeight = cont.clientHeight ? 0 : cont.scrollHeight + "px";
}

const collapseBtns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-collapse]");
[...collapseBtns].forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener("click", collapseTarget ));
```

```css
.cbCollapseRow {
  display: flex;
}

.cbCollapse {
  background-image: url('https://www.pitsco.com/skins/mobile/PlusIcon.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbCollapseRow" data-collapse="#coll1">
  <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
  <h2>Sample 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="content" id="coll1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<button class="cbCollapse" data-collapse="#coll2"></button>
<div class="content" id="coll2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<div class="cbCollapseRow" data-collapse="#coll3">
  <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
  <h2>Sample 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="content" id="coll3">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var content = this.nextElementSibling;`

This means that the element you're trying to collapse/uncollapse is the direct neighbor of the button, which in the case of the first and last elements, is the `h2` tag. Change it to

`var content = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;` and the correct div will be targeted.

Here's the working snippet:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("cbCollapse");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    //This is the changed line VVVVV
    var content = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.cbCollapseRow {
  display: flex;
}

.cbCollapse {
  background-image: url('https://www.pitsco.com/skins/mobile/PlusIcon.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 30px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cbCollapseRow">
    <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
    <h2>Sample 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="cbCollapseRow">
    <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
    <h2>Sample 2</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="cbCollapseRow">
    <button class="cbCollapse"></button>
    <h2>Sample 3</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```